# Webhook for channel's subscriptions

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to know if YouTube offers a webhook system or an event system which sends to a specific endpoint the informations correlated to a specific event (example: a user subscribe to the lowest price subscription of a youtube channel and youtube make an http request to my endpoint with the data of the event like the id of the user who did the subscription and the subscription name). This is useful for me to make some automations when the user make a payed subscription or else. This system already exists on Twitch as "Twitch EventSub" and it would be a shame if youtube doesn't have its webhook system.

I tried to find some info on the official YouTube api documentation but i didn't find anything correlated with webhooks